# Lando pull from pantheon multidev not working

Tags: lando, pantheon

I have installed lando and docker-ce, cloned project from Pantheon and trying to

`lando pull --database=dev --files=dev --code=dev`

after I choose Pantheon account with valid machine key and see this log

```
Attempting to login via terminus...
 [notice] Logging in via machine token.
 [error]  HTTP request has failed with error "Maximum retry attempts reached".
 [error]  Could not find a saved token identified by .
 [error]  Please visit the dashboard to generate a machine token: https://dashboard.pantheon.io/machine-token/create/USER_ID
```

I am sure that machine key is valid, because if I try to run

```
terminus auth:login --email=EMAIL
```

I see

```
[notice] Logged in via machine token.
```

My environment:

1. WSL2 (Focal)
2. Docker version 20.10.9, build c2ea9bc
3. Lando v3.6.4
4. Terminus 3.1.0
5. PHP 8.1.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved via uninstalling docker-ce from WSL2 and installing Docker Desktop on Host machine (check "Use the WSL 2 based engine). After that, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you first run the following?

`lando init --source=pantheon` <-- this should match up your machine token

`lando start`

Then run `lando pull`?

Resource: https://pantheon.io/docs/guides/lando-wordpress#installing-wordpress-using-the-pantheon-recipe

Comment: Hi @bobbiloo, yeap, the project was initialized